# How to run compute on the existing record odoo

Tags: odoo

I have been added an field called **`commission_total`**, it gets the record id as the commission_total computed field, it worked well when any of depending fields change but i need to run the function on all old date not while creating a new change the depends field

```
@api.depends('agents','order_line')
def _compute_commission_total(self):
    total = 0
    for agent in self.agents:
        total += agent.agent_commission
    self.commission_total = total
    _logger.info("COmmisssion total++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    _logger.info(self.commission_total)
```

Comment: Besides the good answer by kerberos: you should change the compute method by using a for loop on `self`, because his answer won't work without that.

Comment: @CZoellner.I want to write server action in my custom module? I don't want to make manually.When I upgrade the module I want to recompute.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could use Odoo server action located in the following path

```
Settings → Technical → Actions → Server Actions
```

create a new action and make sure that the field **Model** is set to the correct model, field **Action To Do** is set to **Execute Python Code**, the **Python Code** field would be your code. which would be something like the following:

```py
all_records = env['Model Name'].search([('Add the preferred domain')]) # you will get all records
for item in all_records:
    item._compute_commission_total()


# or as suggested by @Dipen Shah, you could use
# word `records` as it's available in the context
for item in records:
    item._compute_commission_total()
```

please note that there are available variables in the context as following:

- **env**: Odoo Environment on which the action is triggered
- **model**: Odoo Model of the record on which the action is triggered; is a void recordset
- **record**: record on which the action is triggered; may be void
- **records**: recordset of all records on which the action is triggered in multi-mode; may be void
- useful Python libraries such as **time**, **datetime**, **dateutil**, **timezone**
- **log**: log(message, level='info'): logging function to record debug information in ir.logging table
- **Warning**: Warning Exception to use with raise

if you would like such action to be a source code within your module. it would be an xml file. it could be in `data` folder. it would look like:

```xml
 <record id="action_to_recompute_fields" model="ir.actions.server">
  <field name="name">Recompute the fields</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="model_YOUR_MODEL_NAME"/>
  <field name="state">code</field>
  <field name="code">
for item in records:
    item._compute_commission_total()
  </field>
</record>
```

or you could make it as `Scheduled Actions`

according to your latest comment, if you would like to apply this on existing production database, from your module & not manually. you have to use module versioning which is found in `__manifest__.py` file. so you will increment your module version number. then add `migrations` folder as suggested from the following website: https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maintenance/data-migration.html

you could try this. let us know if it is working.

Comment: On server action, you can better use with records and from their directly you can trigger the method.No need to re-create the environment and search from there.

Comment: I want to write server action in my custom module? I don't want to make manually.When I upgrade the module I want to recompute.Thanks

Comment: How can we cal a compute function on all records from migration?
Suppose I can't do what I want with sql query only.

Answer (score 2):

A way to recompute a field is to:

1. Drop the corresponding database column. You can use psql to run an ALTER TABLE command,
2. Run module upgrade.

I find this easier to remember and, if you have database access, easier to implement.

Comment: I want to write server action in my custom module? I don't want to make manually.When I upgrade the module I want to recompute.Thanks

Comment: I want to make only from my custom module.Thanks

Comment: This is needed only while developing a module, until you get the computation code right. Not needed for deployment, since the column will be naturally created and populated on install or upgrade. So no, you don't need to create some server action for this.